# how to fix this problem "No audience was found based on your search request. Refine your search text."

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-service, administration

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside SP2013.

I did the following:-

1. Create new User Profile service.
2. associated the service with the web application as follow:-

[image]

but the problem i am facing is that if i try to add users to the target audiences inside a wiki page, or inside the site navigation i will always get the following error :-

> No audience was found based on your search request. Refine your search
>   text.

[image]

and i can only assign SharePoint groups as audiences but can not assign individuals ? so can anyone advice on this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audiences have to be built and compiled before they can be used. Audiences are built in the User Profile Service area of Central Administration and are based on user profile properties. For example, you could create a Marketing audience where the membership includes everyone with the Department of Marketing.

Once defined and compiled, it is available in audience selection dialog boxes and should start working as expected.

Comment: so audiences are not by defualt all our Active directory users ?

Comment: They are not, they must be configured separately.

Comment: but inside "site navigation" i define the audiences to be a specif SP group, which prevented other users from seeing the navigation link. and i did this  without adding any audiences from the CA .... so will SP by defualt create Audience for each SP group ???

Comment: You can use AD security groups, Sharepoint groups, or compiled Audiences in the dialog, all should be respected.

Comment: ok i got your point,, but seems that "Target audiences" for a wiki page works differently from "Audiences" inside site navigation. now as i mentioned if i define a SP group as the Audience for a site navigation , then only users that are within this  SP group will see the site navigation.. but inside my enterprise wiki site collection i defined the "Target Audiences" for a wiki page to be specific SP group,, but this did not prevent other users from viewing/editing the wiki page,, so seems "Target Audiences" for a wiki page will not have any effect ,, do u have any idea about this ??

Comment: Audiencing is not security, it merely hides things from the display when applicable. Just because something might be audience trimmed in the navigation doesn't mean the user can't get to it if supplied with the URL. If they must not see it or edit it, then you need you secure it with permissions appropriately.